# Get total count for table row?

Tags: php

I Have an if Statement in  the function is to make  Row Red... if $ced (which is date value coming from MySQL) is lesser than the current time the code is given below: what I am looking for is how can I get total number of rows like 20,30 or whatever the value is and echo

```
<tr <?php if(($ced <= time())): ?> style="color:red;" <?php endif; ?>>
 <td><?php  echo $students_rollno_class;?></td>
 <td><?php  echo $students_admission_no;?> </td>
 <td><?php  echo $students_firstname;?></td>
 <td><?php  echo $students_contact;?></td>
 <td><?php  echo $students_reference_no;?></td>
 <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($students_date));?></td>
 <td><?php  echo $newformat;?></td>
```

what I tried is

```
if(($ced <= time())){ 
$totalCount=$totalCount+1 ;}
```

the problem is its giving me a row numbers like 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4 but i am looking for is single total count like 20

I have a box where I want to show total count the code is given below

```
<div class="info-box-content">
<span class="info-box-text"><?php echo "Course Ended"; ?></span>
<span class="info-box-number"><?php echo $totalCount; ?></span>
 </div>
```

image for reference as the rows are changing to red and i want to show total count in the box 
[image]

Loop i Created but with this its giving me value of 384 as per picture i have only 188 students

```
<?php
if(($ced <= time())){ 
$totalCount=$totalCount+1 ; ?>
 <tr <?php if(($ced <= time())): ?> style="color:red;" <?php endif; ?>>
 <td><?php  echo $students_rollno_class;?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $students_admission_no;?> </td>
      <td><?php  echo $students_firstname;?></td>
       <td><?php  echo $students_contact;?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $students_reference_no;?></td>
         <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($students_date));?></td>
          <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', $ced);?></td>
             </tr><?php }}?>
                       <?php  echo $totalCount;?>
```

**and making all rows red**

Comment: Probably this is inside a loop structure, right ? If so, just print the $totalCount after the loop

Comment: `$totalCount++` does not create multiple values. You are probably outputting this in the wrong place, but you neglected to show us what you actually do with this.

Comment: can please let me know how can I do that as I tried but making all row red

Comment: i added the code where i want to show total count

Comment: What, so you are outputting the value directly after a closing `</tr>` tag here? That does not make much sense either, that would not create a valid HTML table then. And we can’t see where the actual loop ends now, either.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the counts _above_ the table - so how did you achieve that then? Are you looping over the same data set twice, are you doing something else? Please present a _proper_ [mre] of what you are doing, and not just poorly formatted snippets that lack context.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `$totalCount++` to do what you're looking for, it needs to be within some kind of a loop.

You also don't want to echo `$totalCount++`, you want to echo your variable `$totalCount`. This is what contains your total count. The `++` is what increments your value stored in `$totalCount`.

Can you please share the remainder of your code so we can see how you are trying to accomplish this?

Comment: i used this to get the count if(($ced <= time())){  $totalCount=$totalCount+1 ;} and its giving me count 384 even their is only 188 rows

Comment: can you please let me know how can i do that

Comment: Can you share the loop you are using to build these rows?

Comment: added into question after oop I Created but with this it's giving me the value of 384 as per picture I have only 188 students

Comment: Unfortunately what you provided isn't a loop, it is your `if` statement. What we are looking for is something like the following

[For Loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)  

[While Loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)  

[Do While Loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just getting directly in your sql request the data filtered by date `$ced <= time()`

Doing this, you will access directly to the total count without counter, just by calling `count($array)`

Comment: by adding count array its giving me all values i am looking those values which are lesser than current time... i edited the my code above

Comment: Yes but that's why I suggested to directly get only the values you need in the sql request in order to avoid the if statement following because you will already have the values you need.